# Unwanted duplicate image on hover

Tags: css, facebook, image, duplicates, tumblr

I really hate having to result to this, but this problem has me on the edge of my seat.

To make a long story short, I'm trying to add a small music player widget on my site along with a music tab that will display the music player on hover. I've accomplished this, but every time I hover over the music tab icon, it'll move to its designated position but leaves behind an unwanted duplicate of itself.

Here's the first portion of the code:

```
<style type ="text/css">
    #musicplayer{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        position:absolute;left:0px;top:-100px;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        z-index:999;
    }

    #musicplayer:hover{
        top:0px;
    }

    #music{
        padding:3px;
        background: transparent;
        width:175px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left:0px;
        font-family:'Coming Soon';
        z-index: 9999;
        text-align:center;
        padding-left:2px;
        padding-right:2px;
        padding-bottom:70px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

    #musictab{
        font-family: 'Coming Soon';
        height:auto;
        padding:3px;
        background:transparent;
        width:30px;
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        -moz-border-radius:0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    }
</style>
```

And here is the div tag that I think may also be causing the problem

```
<div id="musictab">
    <p><img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/2cpyjv9.jpg" border="0"></a></p>
</div>
```

Please note that there are other `div` tags intrinsic to this code, but I omitted them because I don't think they are causing the problem.

EDIT: Might as well post my website (err, Tumblr page) and you guys can see the problem in action. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Site](http://wrjacobs.tumblr.com)

Comment: you have an erroneous `</a>` in the div tag. Just so you know.

Comment: Is it on purpose you are adding the same tag (with the same id) several times? you also have a div with the same id added several times, ids should be unique - actually it seems your music player is inside a loop it shouldn't be

Comment: I figured the </a> was erroneous and I have actually removed it from the portion of my code before and replaced it, but that still didn't fix the problem I was having. And honestly it isn't intentional. I recently revived my page and had to scrap a ton of my old HTML from the archives of my computer and I'm still trying to sort it out appropriately. If it's causing the problem though, I'd love to know

Comment: you have multimple (about 10 times) added `musicplayer` `div` see the elements inspector, also when you developing, do not switch off context menu it is annoing

Comment: Yeah I should probably turn that back on for the interim. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div id="entry">
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <a href="http://wrjacobs.tumblr.com/post/37948918891/hud-biennial-019">
            <img src="..." alt="hud-biennial-019" width="380px">
        </a>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div class="video"></div>
        <div class="holder"></div>
        <div id="musicplayer">
            <div id="music">
                <center>
                <img... />
                <br>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div id="musictab">
            <p>
                <img src="http://i47.tinypic.com/2cpyjv9.jpg" border="0">
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. close your `<img />` tags! :)
2. this is 1 example of div with the id="entry" - you should only have one element on each page with the same id, e.g. change id="entry" to class="entry".
3. Each time you add an image as an entry, you add the music player for each entry! Meaning you have added the music player 1 x number of entries on the page. This means even though the top musicplayer is correctly shown, moving that will only show the one beneath it - hope that explains it

Comment: All right. Thank you so much! I'll get to work on it and I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Just accepted it. Sorry about that--I just joined a few minutes ago so I'm not really affiliated with the site